# Set breakpoint on JNI_OnLoad

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb

I want to debug some initialzation code in JNI_OnLoad so I need to set up breakpoint inside JNI_OnLoad but I tried ARM DS-5 Commnunity Edition Eclipse plugin and ADT, no luck, just can't do that, anybody happened to know why? thanks.

Comment: Why can't you do that? Which tutorial did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

Set a programmatic breakpoint - something like assert(0). See if it helps.

Comment: That'll just kill the process.  An alternative is to add a log message followed by a sleep(10) call to give you enough time to attach a debugger manually before the code resumes.